# Javascript add +1 to string

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, addition

I have a variable that stores a innerHTML text in it

```
var text = document.getElementById("textID").innerHTML; // <-- textID is actually a number
```

The "text" is actually just a number but I guess javascript still thinks it's a string.

I want to add + 1 to the variable text, but it just adds a new letter instead of increasing the number

**For example : 0 + 1 = 01 --> 01 + 1 = 011 and so on...**

Here's the code I tried this with:

```
text = text + 1;
```

**How can I make it so it increases the number instead of adding new letters? (1+1 = 2, etc)**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Under the assumption that you are absolutely sure that the number is a decimal integer. Either

```
text = +text + 1;
```

Or

```
text = parseInt(text, 10) + 1;
```

Or

```
text = Number(text) + 1;
```

Comment: text = (parseInt(this.text) + 1).toString(); or text = String(parseInt(this.text) + 1)